# Instantiating Boolean object in Java: Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE vs primitives

Tags: java

I want to figure out whether

```
Boolean var = true;
```

is any better than

```
Boolean var = Boolean.True;
```

?

What is an ideological way? Which one is better comparing performance?

After all why there're instantiated Boolean objects if we have two primitives to use?

Comment: The Boolean.True is just a static way of accessing the "primitives". There isn't a big difference between the two.

Comment: using `boolean` you have only `true`and `false`as available values, but by using  `Boolean`there may be cases where you would need to do something  like `Boolean b = null`, in addition to `Boolean.TRUE`& `Boolean.FALSE`values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for `Boolean.TRUE;`

The reason

```
boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE;
```

works is because of autounboxing, a Java 5 feature that allows a wrapper object to be converted to its primitive equivalent automatically when needed. The opposite, autoboxing, is also possible:

```
Boolean boolVar = true;
```

Boolean.TRUE is a reference to an object of the class Boolean, on the other hand, `true` is value of the primitive boolean type. Boolean class is often called "wrapper classes", and are used when you need an object instead of a primitive type.

Comment: It’s correct that `Boolean boolVar = true;` works because of auto(un)boxing. This fact, however, does not explain why the OP should use `Boolean.TRUE` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your two snippets perform identically, because the Java compiler will autobox primitives to their wrapper types (which means the code is effectively identical). The primitive type `boolean` would typically be expected to have slightly better performance, if you did `boolean var = true;` (but it probably isn't measurable).