# Is it better to assign Boolean.TRUE/Boolean.FALSE or true/false to a boolean primitive variable?

Tags: java

While doing some code reviews I stumbled upon this:

People usually assign `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE` value to a boxed boolean variable but use `true`/`false` for primitive variables. What is the best way for this?

According to an architect I worked with - he said that every time you assign `true`/`false` to a variable a new instance of Boolean is created. We can skip that if we assign the boolean variable to the static instances - `Boolean.FALSE`/`Boolean.TRUE`. If the variable is primitive an auto-unboxing is done.

Is the auto-unboxing faster than the initialization of a boolean variable? The differences are not big and I think this is just a micro-optimisation of the code but I wanted to learn more about this.

Comment: If you take this answer for granted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543331/2232127 it suggests that the compiled code is actually equal. Can't find any sources for it though

Comment: @JensV They are functionally equivalent, but do not compile to the same thing.  Which may or may not matter.

Comment: I tried it out here https://gist.github.com/Jenjen1324/9b8971c0dced35333ed99f08e51fb128 and you are right. The bytecode calls `Boolean.valueOf()`

Comment: Both compiled to the same value, does not matter!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right that the performance concerns are mostly a distraction.

To understand what is going on, let's look at how primitives and their boxes are modeled in the Java type system.

When `C extends D`, this means that a `C` *is-a* `D`, or that `C` is a *subtype of* `D`.  When assigning an `Integer` to `Number`, no conversion is required, because an `Integer` is-a `Number`.  Under the hood, both `Integer` and `Number` are represented by pointers (object references) and the assignment is just a pointer copy.

The relationship between `boolean` and `Boolean` is different, though.  There is no `extends`; there is no *is-a*.  Instead, there are *boxing* and *unboxing conversions*, which get applied in certain contexts (e.g., assignment, method parameters.)  Their representations are different.  So when you convert between `boolean` and `Boolean`, the form changes (from a direct representation of the boolean value, to a pointer to a heap node containing an object header and a boolean payload.)  This is why people warn you about "the performance cost"; it's not just copying one word.  (That said, if this is the performance bottleneck in your program, you've got bigger problems -- namely that your program doesn't do very much.)

When you assign

```
boolean b = true;
```

or

```
Boolean bb = Boolean.TRUE;
```

the types on both sides of the `=` are the same -- `boolean` in the first example, `Boolean` in the second -- and there is no conversion.  When you do

```
boolean b = Boolean.TRUE;
```

or

```
Boolean bb = true;
```

the types are different, and there is a conversion required.  The compiler silently translates these to:

```
boolean b = Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue();
```

and

```
Boolean bb = Boolean.valueOf(true);
```

In the specific case of `boolean`, the performance concerns are *even less relevant* than for other primitives, since there are only two boolean values, and the constants `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` are interned.

If your architect gave you this advice primarily on performance concerns, then he/she was misguided.  If their advice was motivated more by simplicity -- that it is equally easy to use a value of the correct type that requires no conversion -- this is sensible.

Comment: Addendum: the fact that the compiler (or *common compilers*) compile `Boolean bb = true;` to `Boolean bb = Boolean.valueOf(true);` is not mandated by the specification. A compiler could generate `Boolean bb = Boolean.TRUE;` instead, without violating the specification. The biggest reason that no-one has implemented such an optimization, is precisely that it doesn’t matter in practice.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a primitive boolean variable, then assign true or false to avoid performing the unboxing.

if you have a wrapper Boolean variable, then use Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE to avoid performing boxing and/or instantiation of a new object.

Comment: What do you gain by "preventing" autoboxing? It's a step the compiler performs, at runtime you have equal performance. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html _Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes_

Comment: Autoboxing is done only if you are assigning a primitive value to a wrapper variable, while auto-un-boxing is done only if you are assigning a wrapper variable to a primitive value

Comment: But you are suggesting using `Boolean.TRUE` when assigning to `Boolean` even though assigning `true` causes Autoboxing to happen which essentially makes the code equivalent. So you get the same result but no unnecessary complexity by sometimes using `Boolean.TRUE` and sometimes `true`.

Comment: if you assign Boolean.TRUE to Boolean no autoboxing is done, only the instantiation of Boolean.TRUE during the first evaluation of the variable in a single execution of an application.
Assiging true instead causes autoboxing any time you make the assignment to a variable of type Boolean.

Comment: I agree with that, I'm questioning why you should *avoid* autoboxing. The performance gain is pretty much zero. Brian's answer makes more sense to me in that regard

Comment: He is simply asking for differences even in micro-terms just for theorical reasons